# Android Dev: Can't generate multiple layouts dynamically from an XML template

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, dynamic

Making a simple program which will generate a multiple choice form.  I have an sing_select.xml which acts as the template for making each question.  Then, in code I wanted to populate my main.xml with a bunch of these templates customized.  Though it works great for the first question, any subsequent questions do not get displayed.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I know there isn't an overlap as I manually hid the first question.

Java File

```
public class FormFillerActivity extends Activity
{
    private LinearLayout    mQuestionList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Must come before setContentView or program crashes
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Must set before accessing layout elements or program crashes
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mQuestionList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Body_Layout);

        initForm();
    }

    private void initForm()
    {
        int count = 1;

        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
        answers.add("Single");
        answers.add("Married");
        answers.add("Separated");
        answers.add("Divorced");
        mQuestionList.addView(addSingSelectQuestion(count++, "What is your marital status?", answers));

        answers.clear();
        answers.add("Male");
        answers.add("Female");
        mQuestionList.addView(addSingSelectQuestion(count++, "What is your gender?", answers));

    }

    private View addSingSelectQuestion(int count, String question, ArrayList<String> answers)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sing_select, null);

        ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.Sing_Select_Num)).setText(count + ") ");
        ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.Sing_Select_Text)).setText(question);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) container.findViewById(R.id.Sing_Select_Answer);

        //Generate radio group answers
        Iterator<String> it = answers.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(rg.getContext());
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            String ans = it.next();

            rb.setId(answers.indexOf(ans));
            rb.setLayoutParams(params);
            rb.setText(ans);
            rb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            rb.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.txt_normal));
            rg.addView(rb);
        }

        return container;
    }
}
```

main.xml (stripped out unrelated UI elements)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Body_Scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/Title"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Body_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marg_normal"
            android:padding="@dimen/pad_large" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
...
```

sing_select.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Sing_Select_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sing_Select_Num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="#) "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sing_Select_Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Sing_Select_Num"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Sing_Select_Num"
        android:text="The Question?"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_normal" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/Sing_Select_Answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Sing_Select_Text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Sing_Select_Text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Sing_Select_Trans_Button" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sing_Select_Trans_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_big"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Accept"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set orientation to `vertical` for the *Body_Layout* `LinearLayout`. I think your pushing out of the screen the next rows after the first one(the width for the inflated view is set to fill the parent).

Comment: Man I'm such an idiot. That fixed it. Hate it when I miss things like that.

Comment: sorry man. new to posting here. Didn't know I could do that. Should be marked now.